# Short story identification: A boy visits a futuristic zoo and gets injured by a gorilla

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A boy, on a trip to a futuristic zoo with his father, suffers an accident involving a gorilla.

He is rushed to surgery.

After a futile attempt, the surgeon informs the boy's father that he was unable to save the boy's arm, but that:

> he still has two "good" arms remaining. The mutation is the result of a nuclear war.

Any direction is appreciated.

By way of further information, I am a high school librarian, and one of my students is a voracious consumer of Sci-Fi. I've fed him much of what I have, but we were talking about how I started to read Sci-Fi, and this was the story that started it all. It introduced me to the genre and also the beauty of a well-written short story.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/214789/old-sci-fi-story-radiation-mutated-the-animals-a-boy-loses-a-limb-but-its-ok (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 5):

I think it might be Zoo 2000 by Richard Curtis in the anthology of the same name edited by Jane Yolen. I've also been looking for this story for a while as it got me into sci-fi and fantasy genre too :)
 http://www.philsp.com/homeville/isfac/t97.htm#A2177

Answer (score 5):

The boy loses his arm but there's a twist, right? Yes, that's [Zoo 2000](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2598901-zoo-2000-twelve-stories-of-science-fiction-and-fantasy-beasts), the story and anthology, and I read it in middle school.

That book helped set me on a good road. I can still see the font on the cover, and the binding was tan. It made an impression.

[image]